# What does "Internal Serialization Error" mean and how to fix in ClickHouse?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, upload, clickhouse

Attempting to write a dataframe of all strings to a table

Here is what pandas says the data types are when i execute `df.dtypes`

| Column Name | dtype |
| --- | --- |
| id | object |
| location | object |
| major_class | object |

```py
client=clickhouse_connect.create_client(
    host='localhost',
    username='default',
    password='',
    compression='zstd',
)
try:
    client.insert_df(table=table,df=df,database='default')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    client.close()
```

Produces
"Internal serialization error.  This usually indicates invalid data types in an inserted row or column"

docker image is altinity/clickhouse-server:22.8.13.21.altinitystable

using clickhouse-connect==0.5.13 to upload

I expected the dataframe to upload just fine. Got an error instead.

Comment: This is a possible bug.  What kind of column(s) are you inserting into?

Comment: It sounds like a bug. Repro is needed to be able to diagnoze in further like @GeoffGenz says. Better to issue the new bug report to https://github.com/ClickHouse/clickhouse-connect/

Alternatively, you can check if the problem also happens with this driver: https://github.com/mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver
It's community-supported (not ClickHouse inc), but more mature. Also it uses Native protocol, not HTTP (so pay attention: you will need to use port 9000, not 8123)

Comment: @GeoffGenz, All the columns that I am inserting into are of type `String`.

Comment: Can you give the full stack trace of the error (or as @filimonov said), open an issue in the clickhouse-connect github?  We've tested the 0.5.13 version with much more complex dataframe inserts without any problems, so additional information is necessary to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Before this code I was concatenating multiple DataFrames together and it looks like one of the columns had an integer in there. 

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code to cast all columns to the correct data type before inserting.

change

```py
client.insert_df(table=table,df=df,database='default')
```

to

```py
client.insert_df(table=table,df=df.astype(str),database='default')
```